# Ansible playbook: pipeline local cmd output (e,g. git archive) to server?

Tags: deployment, sftp, ansible, server-configuration

So my project has a special infrastructure, the server has only SSH connection, I have to upload my project code to server using SSH/SFTP everytime, manually. The server can not fetch.

Basically I need something like `git archive master | ssh user@host 'tar -zxvf -'` automatically done using playbook.

I looked at docs, `local_action` seems to work but it requires a local ssh setup.  Are there other ways around?

Comment: what do you mean by local ssh setup?

Comment: @helloV it means master machine must have ssh. see http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this. You may have to tweak to suit your needs.

```
 tasks:
    - shell: git archive master /tmp/master.tar.gz
    - unarchive: src=/tmp/master.tar.gz dest={{dir_to_untar}}
```

I still do not understand `it requires a local ssh setup` in your question.

Comment: hey, I found the [unarchive module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/unarchive_module.html) is extremely useful. thanks. May need first add another task under `connection: local` , then combined with an extra arg like `unarchive: copy=yes`  it works!

Comment: `copy=yes` is default, don't have to specify